# Get the character and its count which has highest occurrence

Tags: c#

I have this C# method which get the character and its count which has highest occurrence

```
    public KeyValuePair<char, int> CountCharMax_Dictionary_LINQ(string s)
    {
        char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();

        var result = chars.GroupBy(x => x)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count())
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return result;
    }
```

It works but is there any better or efficient way to get the same result? Is there any difference if I return it as Tuple vs KeyValuePair?

Test data:

- Input: 122. Expected Output: 2,1
- Input: 122111. Expected Output: 1,4

Comment: The expected output for input "122" should be "2, 2", not "2, 1".

Comment: Ops yeah. Indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19522559/3312), it would be wiser to use a tuple in this case. I use lowercase "t"uple as I highly recommend the built-in language support for tuples `(char, int)` over the explicit `Tuple<T1, T2>` declaration, etc. Few more points:

- What should happen in a tie? Which gets returned? If any is acceptable, it's fine as-is. To be more of a determinate function, secondarily order by the character itself.
- Don't need to convert it to a character array as a string already *is* a character array.
- Re-order the `OrderByDescending` and the `Select` so that `Count` only has to be called once.
- It can be made `static` since it doesn't access class instance data.
- It can be made an extension method if in a `static` class.
- It can be made into an expression-bodied method.
- Maybe consider a better name; one that confers what it does rather than how it does it.

All that said, here's my take:

```
    public static (char, int) MaxCharacterFrequency(this string s) =>
        s.GroupBy(x => x)
         .Select(x => (x.Key, x.Count()))
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2)
         .ThenBy(x => x.Item1)
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `It can be made static since it doesn't access class instance data.` If the method doesn't access to class instance data, with static, it is safer and use less memory?

Comment: I would say that objectively it does use less memory for two reasons: 1. The class instance is not required to be created and 2. The implicit `this` parameter is not passed to the method. It's not anything substantial, but it's more of an idiomatic correctness to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much to add to Slicers answer other than underscore in names is rather un-C#-ish, and you should avoid single character names (`s`) as well.

You ask for more efficient ways for the algorithm. One could be the following:

```
public (char value, int count) MaxByFrequency(string input)
{
  var chars = input.ToCharArray();
  Array.Sort(chars);
  char value = ' ';
  int max = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; )
  {
    int j = i;
    char ch = chars[j];
    while (j < chars.Length && chars[j] == ch) j++;

    if (j - i > max)
    {
      max = j - i;
      value = ch;
    }

    i = j;
  }

  return (value, max);
}
```

It is efficient time wise (in my measures more than twice as fast) but of cause is rather "expensive" in memory usage because of the temporary array of chars.

---

Another linq approach using `Aggregate` could be:

```
public (char value, int count) MaxByFrequency(string input)
{
  (char value, int count) seed = (' ', 0);
  return input
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Aggregate(seed, (acc, gr) =>
    {
      int cnt = gr.Count();
      if (cnt > acc.count)
        return (gr.Key, cnt);
      return acc;
    });
}
```